# \subsubsection in a report style document

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, report

I am trying to make a subsubsection in a report document. It does this successfully, however it removes the subsection from the contents section of the document.

Is there anyway to rectify this?

I tried using, for example,

`\addcontentsline{toc}{subsubsection}{Photoelectric Effect}`

but this does not work. Nothing shows up.

Comment: Use `\subsubsection{title here}`. Compile twice.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The default *depth* of the ToC in [`report`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/report.cls) is 2 (contained within the counter `tocdepth`). This means that sectional units up to and including this *level* will be included in the ToC. Here are the levels based on the standard document classes:

- `\part` = -1
- `\chapter` = 0
- `\section` = 1
- `\subsection` = 2
- `\subsubsection` = 3
- `\paragraph` = 4
- `\subparagraph` = 5

If you wish for your subsubsections to be included, add

```
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}% Include \subsubsection in ToC
```

to your document preamble. Here's a MWE showing the resulting output:

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}% Include \subsubsection in ToC
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{A chapter}
\section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection}
\subsubsection{A subsubsection}
\end{document}
```

Note that `\subsubsection`s are not numbered by default. If you wish to have them numbered (in the ToC as well), then you also need to include

```
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}% Number \subsubsection
```

in the preamble also. The default, just like `tocdepth` is `2`. Here's an view with the update:

[image]