# Subsubsection not appearing in the table of contents (report class)

Tags: table-of-contents, report

I have a large project (report class) in which I am importing separate files.
What I would like to do is using subsubsections in the report class, and let them appear in the table of contents with numbered titles for the subsubsections.

A similar problem answered [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/418117/table-of-contents-subsubsection-numbering) for toptesi, but I have not managed to cusomise it for my report.
There are brief descriptions of what is going on.
I would highly appreciate your help.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{import} 
% For subsubsection in report class
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3} 

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% LINE SPACING
\newcommand{\linespacing}{1.5}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{\linespacing}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\pagestyle{plain}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% HYPERREF
\usepackage[colorlinks,pagebackref,pdfusetitle,urlcolor=blue,citecolor=blue,linkcolor=blue,bookmarksnumbered,plainpages=false]{hyperref}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

% TABLE OF CONTENTS
\newpage
\pdfbookmark[0]{Contents}{contents_bookmark}
\tableofcontents


\chapter{Introduction}
\input{file1}
    
\end{document}
```

In file1.tex, I have these.

```
\section{Section File1}\label{file1}
\subsection{Subsection File1}
    \subsubsection{Subsub section 1}
    \subsubsection{Subsub section 2}
    \subsubsection{Subsub section 3}
```

The current outputs are
[image]
[image]

Comment: Possibly related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/146304/subsubsection-in-a-report-style-document

Comment: @brignall Indeed...! Thank you for pointing this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set also tocdepth

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{report}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3} %<--------
\pagestyle{plain}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Introduction}
\section{Section File1}\label{file1}
\subsection{Subsection File1}
    \subsubsection{Subsub section 1}
    \subsubsection{Subsub section 2}
    \subsubsection{Subsub section 3}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! I don't know why I was blind about that line...